# How to obtain copy of Starling without errors OR how to fix Starling errors

Tags: flash-builder, starling-framework

I set up my development environment to learn Starling today. I watched the video at [Starling Tutorial Video 1](https://youtu.be/RTvhZ8wbJaQ) on YouTube, and I followed the steps. Toward the end of the video, the presenter notes that I should make sure there are no errors and run my program.

The assumption is that "make sure there are no errors" applies to the code that we have just written. I have no errors in the two files that I created along with the video instructor. However, I have 54 errors that exist within the newly installed Starling framework, which I am not yet experienced enough to debug and correct (see image).

The package that I installed for Starling is the latest release available from their website on the main page.  I am using Flash Builder as recommended by their tutorial, and, clearly Flash has been advanced several generations since the tutorial was first created.

Is there a place where I can download a copy of Starling that has been upgraded to match the current version of flash and uses the correct ActiveScript 3 syntax?

Alternatively, are there any recommendations for bypassing or overlooking errors in a code base that is not mine to maintain?

Any help provided is appreciated. The screenshot below shows the 54 errors in the Starling packages.

Note: Most of the errors seem to regard Context3D objects. And I believe all instances of the errors regard "possibly undefined methods" being used, or an "possibly undefined property" being accessed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some helpful resources:

- [Bulletin Board Discussion](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/starting-with-starling)
- [Instructions for Installing Air SDK that are better than the YouTube video](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/using_air_with_asc_1)

I had to install the playerglobal.swc files and Air SDK multiple times. Eventually, I deleted all 11.1 folders to remove any potential conflicts.

On the last attempt to recreate the project, I noticed that the swc files were being loaded from the eclipse folder. The playerglobal.swc file was updated there, because I replaced ALL playerglobal.swc files. However, this copy of the Air SDK was not the latest release that I had installed.

I carefully matched each file loaded in the eclipse folder to the corresponding files in the '4.6.0 air 3.4' folder.

Once I did this, the compiler errors went away. Now I am getting ReferenceErrors during the build process, but that is a separate issue and unrelated to the above question.

Advice to those who follow:

1. Make sure, when you create your new Action Script project, that you load the swc files from the 4.6.0 folder or the 4.6.0 folder that you merged with the AIR SDK.
2. Save yourself some time and reduce risk of errors by using the `ditto` command to merge the AIR SDK into the 4.6.0 folder.
3. If you are still having trouble, delete references to old code-base versions to prevent any chance of accidental references being used.